# How to install SteamOS with Seam OS installer solving Debian Installer error?

Tags: steam-os

It throws an error message stating that it could not find this file as you can see from the image below.

[image]

Comment: SteamOS is a Linux distro like any other. Make the necessary provisions for space if you want to dual boot then make a bootable USB (or burn it to DVD), boot from it and follow instructions.

Comment: Thank you man!! MichaelBay  for saving my day!! Initially I was bit confused there as this is all new to me thanks again man!!